# Inequality of $|e^z - 1|$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, modules, rouches-theorem

I'm doing a problem related with Rouché Theorem and to prove it I need to show the following inequality:
$|e^z - 1| < e - 1$ if $|z| < 1$.

I've seen that $|e^z - 1| \leq e + 1$ and that $|e^z| \leq e$ if $|z| < 1$. But I can't manage to get that $|e^z - 1| < e - 1$.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$|e^z-1|=|\sum_{n \ge1}\frac{z^n}{n!}| \le \sum_{n \ge1}|\frac{z^n}{n!}| < \sum_{n \ge1}\frac{1}{n!}=e-1$ since $|z| < 1$ so $|z|^n <1$ for all $n$

Comment: Omg! So clean! Helped a lot, thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help! (this type of inequality is true for all functions with Taylor series with non-negative coefficients)